# Extract Date from text using nltk and pos tagging , python

Tags: python-3.x, text, nlp, nltk

I am trying to extract dates from text with formats being like **January 2017 to February 2018** or **Jan 2018 to Feb 2018**. I am using nltk and i am getting pos tags of each sentence.I want to extract tuple of all the dates with date's in date range like **January 2017 to February 2018**. How do i get the relevant information. Currently i am using pattern matching with regex and extracting sentences with set of words in it. Is there any other better approach and how can i capture the required tuples.

My code:

```
res_lines = []
for res in parsed_resume:
    try:
        text = res['content']
        lines = [line.strip() for line in text.split("\n") if len(line) > 0]
        lines = [nltk.word_tokenize(line) for line in lines]
        lines = [nltk.pos_tag(line) for line in lines]
    except(AttributeError) as e:
        pass
    res_lines.append(lines)
```

res_lines contains list of all the tokenized and pos tags of sentences. To capture this pattern i can capture postags where NNP is followed by CD for January(NNP) 2018(CD).

Sample text:

```
JOB DETAILS
FROM     TO COMPANY  JOB TITLE
AUGUST 2019 OCTOBER 2019    ALMANSOORI PRODUCTION SERVICE, OMAN.
JUNE  2019  JULY  2019  ALMANSOORI PRODUCTION SERVICE, KENYA.
JANUARY 2018    MAY  2019   ALMANSOORI PRODUCTION SERVICE, OMAN.
JUNE 2015   DECEMBER 2017   GAS AND OILFIELD SERVICES COMPANY(GOFSCO)
SEPTEMBER 2010  JUNE 2015   OIL TEST WELL SERVICE LIMITED
```

How do i execute this logic?

Comment: Hi, why don't you try NER which has a tag for the dates?

Comment: What is `line` ? I cannot see where you instantiate it.

Comment: I am using POS tagging for this, and lines are initiated in the loop itself